# how does threads and method calls gets allocated on stacks in java?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, stack

Each thread in the JVM gets its own stack and they are private. The common resources are accessible from the Heap, which are available to all threads. Let's consider the following code:

```
public class Test {
   public static int getNum(num) {
      return num;
   }
   public static void main(String[ ] args) {
       int x = getNum(5);
       System.out.println(x);
   }
}
```

Once the `Test` class is loaded, there is one thread which is the `main` that gets executed. The method `getNum` is stored in the method area of the non-heap memory, according to this article
http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-jvm-memory-types/

A stack for the main thread is allocated. Now I have two method calls inside this thread. One is `getNum` which returns an `int`, and next is `System.out.println` (static method of `Printstream` class).

So do I get to make a new `Stack` inside the `main stack` where the first method call gets executed and it returns to main thread to store in variable `x` and a new stack for `println` whose return type is `void?`
how does this progressive stack work? or am I getting something wrong here...

Comment: _static method of Printstream class_ This is not true. `println()` is an instance method.

Comment: The thread starts. `main()` is pushed, `getNum()` is pushed, `getNum()` is popped, `println()` is pushed and popped, `main()` is popped. The compiled byte code gives a good idea of this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis not everyone can read byte code. The same way not everyone can read ASM.

Comment: @Cruncher Sure, it takes practice. You (anyone) should be able to follow along with instructions like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings).

Comment: As it stands your stack is never more than 2 deep. If you print inside the getNum() method, then your stack will get 3 deep, as it needs to allocate the new stack before getNum returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the difference between a *stack* and a *stack frame*.

There is one stack per thread. Each stack consists of frames. When `main` performs the first method call, a new stack frame gets allocated, then `getNum` is called, and then the frame gets deallocated. Now it's turn to call `println`. Again, a new stack frame is allocated, the call is performed, and the frame gets deallocated. If `println` makes some method calls of its own, new frames get allocated and deallocated on the same stack to accommodate the call sequence. Stack frames get destroyed in the order opposite to their creation order (that's the reason why this structure is called a "stack" in the first place).

Note that allocating and deallocating stack frames is very efficient, because it's often an operation supported directly by the CPU's hardware.

Comment: is it correct say to stack frames as small bits of stack? I can imagine stack as a small piece of memory but how to imagine a stack frame, it is still a fragmented memory of the base stack correct?

Comment: @user2708477 Stack frames can be bigger or smaller, depending on the function being called, but they are relatively small. The stack itself can be called "a small piece of memory" only in a relative sense: it's 512K on 32-bit systems, and 1M on 64-bit systems.